# Execute method on exception raised without rescuing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using Sidekiq, and I'd like to execute a method when an exception is raised in a background job, without rescuing the error.

Currently, I have:

```
begin 
  # job
rescue => SomeError
  # run method
end
```

However, since it rescues the error, it does not go in the "failed" section of Sidekiq.

I'd like to execute code when an exception is raised, but without rescuing it. How can I do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just re-raise and you are all set.

```
begin 
  # job
rescue => SomeError
  # run method
  raise
end
```

Comment: Damn. So obvious, should have thought about it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Welcome; I have been there in “so obvious” land many times :)